# What happens to http request for which client timed out?

Tags: http, timeout, connection-timeout, http-response-codes

I believe I understood `http client connection timeout` vs `server request timeout` and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49705331/1592312) did a pretty good job in explaining same.

However what I couldn't found anywhere is what happens to http request received by server but client timed out. Basically what http status code I should be logging for such requests ?